# I want to customize Admob at Ionic 3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, admob, ionic3

I implemented Ionic Native's Admob Free.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/

Then, ads are always fixed at the bottom.

Is it impossible to display this in any position?
Can I do with Admob Pro?

If you know something, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [AdMob Free plugin documentation](https://ratson.github.io/cordova-plugin-admob-free/function/index.html#static-function-setOptions), you can place the ad at top or bottom.

To place it on top you have to set *bannerAtTop* as *true* in the config.

```
const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
    ...
    bannerAtTop: true,
};
this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
```

But, in the [AdMob Pro](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-pro/), you can set the x,y coordinates position in pixels using *showBannerAtXY()* method. [Here is the documentation](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/1.3-Methods-for-Banner#admobshowbanneratxyx-y).